# Heart rate update frequency on Phone

Tags: ios, watchkit, healthkit

I have an iOS 10 iPhone app, with a WatchKit 3 Watch app extension.

The Watch app is running an `HKWorkoutSession`, and successfully querying `.heartRate` data. A sample is returned about every 5 seconds.

The phone app is running a similar query, but generally returns an empty samples array, although occasionally will return a batch of samples representing a longer period of data from the watch (10 minute's worth, say). Presumably this is a battery saving tactic by the watch.

**Is it possible for the phone app to query heartRate from HealthStore at a similar rate to the watch app, or for the watch to push data through HealthKit more frequently?**

I can work around this by pushing data from the watch to the phone using `WCSession`'s `sendMessage(_:replyHandler:errorHandler:)` - but I'd prefer it if I could just query HealthKit directly on the phone.

Comment: Also curious about this...